# How to use a Percentage discount as Independent Variable in regression analysis

Tags: regression, percentage

I want to run a regression analysis where my dependent variable is the number of cars registered and my independent variable is the percentage discount given. I am not sure how to use a percentage discount as an IV?
Do I just use the percentage as it is, eg. 35% would be 0.35 or is there another way to do this?

It would be great if someone could help!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

use "Discount" as your independent variable, put inside it the percentage of discounts you would like to apply (0, 0.15, 0.30, etc...) and include that column in your regression